# Flutter - Creating lists with different types of items

Tags: flutter

Im trying to use this technique from the cookbook https://flutter.io/cookbook/lists/mixed-list/... However, MessageItems per header are N and not static... How do i use this code example for N MessageItems per header?

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> buildByDateFb(
    String documentRef, GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldState) {
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: Firestore.instance
        .collection("schedule")
        .document(documentRef.toLowerCase())
        .collection("by_date")
        .orderBy("day")
        .orderBy("time")
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
      final int messageCount = snapshot.data.documents.length;

      List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
      for(DocumentSnapshot item in snapshot.data.documents) {
        var heading = HeadingItem(item['day']);
        var row = MessageItem(item['className'], item['leadBy'], item['time']);
        items.add(heading);
        items.add(row);
      }

      return StickyList.builder(
        itemCount: messageCount,
        builder: (_, int index) {
          final item = items[index];

          if (item is HeadingItem) {
            return HeaderRow(
                child: _buildRowHeaderContents(item.day.toString())
            );
          } else if (item is MessageItem) {
            return RegularRow(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: new CircleAvatar(
                    child: new Text(item.time.toString()),
                    radius: 27.0,
                  ),
                  title: new Text(item.className),
                  subtitle: Text(item.leadBy)
                )
            );
          }
        },
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: you can do it using Slivers , check this great article by one of the flutter team : https://medium.com/flutter-io/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f

Comment: Thank you, but i dont think you understand my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use sticky headers with different types of classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53072460/how-do-i-use-sticky-headers-with-different-types-of-classes)

Answer (score 0):

If `MessageItem` that you're handling in the List is dynamic, you may want to consider the type of message to be displayed (i.e. text, image, video) and track it in the Firestore document. With this approach, it can determine which Widget should be used to display the `MessageItem`.